# rust return type issue in simple function

Tags: function, csv, rust, return-type

I'm having a misunderstanding about return types in rust. coming from JavaScript and thinking I understood the core concepts of mutating, scopes, etc. But now I'm stuck at a simple return type.

```rust
fn main() {
  let input = "./assets/input.csv";
  let list = get_csv(&input);

  for result in list.records() {
    let record = result?;
    println!("{:?}", record);
  }
}


fn get_csv(csv_path: &str) -> csv::Reader {
  return csv::Reader::from_path(csv_path);
}
```

I will get the error

```
mismatched types

expected struct `csv::Reader`, found enum `std::result::Result`

note: expected struct `csv::Reader<&str>`
           found enum `std::result::Result<csv::Reader<std::fs::File>, csv::Error>`
note: to return `impl Trait`, all returned values must be of the same type
note: for information on `impl Trait`, see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#returning-types-that-implement-traits>
help: you could instead create a new `enum` with a variant for each returned typerustc(E0308)
```

UPDATE:

```rust
fn get_csv (filepath: &str) -> csv::Result<csv::Reader<File>>{
    let mut reader =  csv::ReaderBuilder::new();
    let mut list = match reader
    .delimiter(b';')
    .from_path(&filepath) {
        Ok(list) => list,
        Err(error) => {
            println!("Failed to open file. {}", error);
            return;
        }
    };
    return list;
}
```

Comment: There are a few things wrong here. 1. `main` needs to a return a `Result` in order to use `?`. 2. The return type of `Read::from_path` is a `Result` so `get_csv` needs that too. 3. `list` needs to be mutable.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=138d7155b1d6c6c146c588d317f3f293

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is telling you that what the method returns (`Result`) is different from what you have defined (`csv::Reader`). When you check the [documentation](https://docs.rs/csv/1.1.6/csv/struct.Reader.html#method.from_path) for the `from_path` method, you see that it is defined as:

```
pub fn from_path<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> Result<Reader<File>>
```

The return value of the function is a `Result` enum that has two states: `Ok` or `Err`. If for example the given file doesn't exist, you cannot create a reader for it. In your code, you have to handle the case that the reader cannot be created. For example:

```
use csv::Reader;

fn main() {
    let input = "./assets/input.csv";

    let mut list = match Reader::from_path(&input) {
        Ok(list) => list,
        Err(error) => {
            println!("Failed to open file. {}", error);
            return;
        }
    };

    for result in list.records() {
        let record = result.unwrap();
        println!("{:?}", record);
    }
}
```

The Rust book has more information on the `Result` enum: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html

The `Reader` that gets returned in the `Result` is a [generic type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-01-syntax.html), which means that it provides a generic implementation that can be used with different concrete Rust types. `Reader<File>` is the notation that tells the Rust compiler that this instance of `Reader` is used to read from a `File`. But technically, `Reader` supports anything that implements the `std::io::Read` trait (see the [source](https://docs.rs/csv/1.1.6/src/csv/reader.rs.html#816)). For example, you could use to read CSV files from a network stream, or have the user type them into `STDIN` and read them from the terminal line-by-line.

Comment: thanks, that was a pretty good read, i will need to look more into `Result` and `Match` as those are topics i have to use more in order to fully understand them.

while your example works flawless, i still have a hard time with the correct return type:

`csv::Result<csv::Reader<File>>`
where i can't seem to find where `File` is from. Could you also share how you got to know where File is From? 

thanks for the great answer, nonetheless! :)

Comment: `Result` is a very common pattern in Rust, so it is definitely good to learn it. I've added a section on the `Reader` type and what the notation `Reader<File>` means. Check out the documentation on generics as well, and don't get discouraged if it doesn't click right away. This part can be a bit difficult to learn.